# Debugging with CreateProcess

Tags: delphi, winapi, windows-8

I'm using `CreateProcess` with `DEBUG_ONLY_THIS_PROCESS` flag. The new process is created, but the newly run application doesn't do anything and when I look at the process list with Task Manager, all I see is the name of the exe file with only 70KB of memory allocated!

If I create the process without `DEBUG_ONLY_THIS_PROCESS` flag, the application is run perfectly.

This is my code:

```
function TDebugger.StartDebug;
var
  ProcInfo: TProcessInformation;
  ProcessCreationFlags: Cardinal;
  StartupInfo: TStartupInfo;
  DE: TDebugEvent;
begin
  // == init process info
  ZeroMemory(@ProcInfo, SizeOf(TProcessInformation));
  // == init startup info
  ZeroMemory(@StartupInfo, SizeOf(TStartupInfo));
  with StartupInfo do begin
    cb := SizeOf(TStartupInfo);
    lpDesktop := '';
    dwX := CW_USEDEFAULT;
    dwY := CW_USEDEFAULT;
    dwXSize := CW_USEDEFAULT;
    dwYSize := CW_USEDEFAULT;
    wShowWindow := SW_SHOWDEFAULT;
  end;
  // == Create the process
  ProcessCreationFlags := DEBUG_ONLY_THIS_PROCESS;
  if (not CreateProcess(PWideChar(Path), Nil, Nil, Nil, False, ProcessCreationFlags, Nil, PWideChar(CurrentDirectory), StartupInfo,
    ProcInfo)) then
      RaiseLastOSError;

end;
```

I think there is some API function I should call after creating the process, but I have no idea what it is.
Can anyone help me with this problem?

**Additional Info:** My main application is an IDE and it needs to debug its player application.

Comment: I'm also trying to create a user mode debugger. Were you able to create your Debugger? Could you share your code or would it be available on github? My project is an open source project on github and I'm trying to create a debugger using the dbgeng.dll (Debugger Engine) with Delphi. Any tips would be great.

Comment: @ThomasJaeger I figured it out and fixed the problem, however, in the end I used `IPC` which in my case worked just fine. It's been a long time so I don't remember what my code was. Sorry.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you create a process for debugging, with DEBUG_ONLY_THIS_PROCESS, the process does not actually start running. It waits for your debugger to start it up. So, yes, you do have to call some functions to get the process up and running. You now you need to write your debugger! The main body of which is your debugger loop.

Some references that might help:

- [Creating a basic debugger (MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679288.aspx)
- [Writing a basic Windows debugger (Code Project)](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/43682/Writing-a-basic-Windows-debugger)